Does Prometheus Summary Metrics loses its state when the client service is restarted?
We have a service for which we log server metrics to prometheus. earlier we were using histogram metrics but it was logging a lot of raw metrics which were not needed and it was increasing the load on our prometheus server. we decided to switch to summary for these metrics.
I read the the summary metrics calculates the percentile values using ranks (I know this is oversimplification of the actual logic) on client side - our service in this case - only and this reduces the load on the prometheus server.
If we restart our service, do we lose all the previously calculated values/ranks - state of the summary metrics - and if yes, could this impact the metrics logged to the prometheus?
I feel like I'm missing something here as this seems like a pretty common pitfall which should've have been handled by prometheus library itself. So please lmk what I'm missing here.
Thanks in advance.

Yes, all metrics start at 0 when the process starts. Should be easy to verify with a simple test application
